# If not in the EVM, where do internal functions execute?

Tags: evm, internal-transactions, function

The [Ethereum documentation](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/smart-contracts/anatomy/#functions) says that `internal` functions are not executed in the EVM, while `external` ones are:

[image]

If not in the EVM, where are internal functions executed? Does this simply mean that `internal` functions are executed wholly within the one node the call is made within, while `external` functions end up being broadcast to the entire network (all nodes)?

Comment: all functions are executed within EVM, although external can be called by another contract which is a holy grail of composability of Ethereum, and it makes smart contracts interoperable within the chain

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`internal` functions are called through a [JUMP](https://www.ethervm.io/#56) / [JUMPI](https://www.ethervm.io/#57) instruction, simply jumping to another point of the current code. This makes sense because internal functions do not change context (*i.e.,* they stay inside the same contract). To make things clearer, you can only call an internal function if you are running a contract's code, which imply that a call was made to that contract to begin with, it's just that calling an internal function doesn't require (nor allow) an EVM call to reach it directly, only jumps.

`external` functions on the other hand can only be called through an internal [EVM call](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/core/vm/instructions.go#L667).

You can read more about it in the solidity [documentation](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.13/control-structures.html?highlight=internal#internal-function-calls).

I hope that answers your question.

Comment: Looks like I was conflating "doesn't create an additional EVM call" with "doesn't execute within the EVM". Thank you!